# Late binding in C# and .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, late-binding

I am trying to convert this code to C# .NET Framework 3.5 but that version is not late binding friendly. If I were using 4.0 I'd use a dynamic type but that's not an option right now.

Complicating things is the object I really want to create (`atl3270Tool`) is created inside a parameter. Help would be appreciated.

```
Dim atl3270Tool
Dim ErrMsg As String
Dim S_OK As UInt16 = 0
Dim atlDirectorObject = CreateObject("atlDirectorObject.atlDirector")
If atlDirectorObject.CreateTool("3270", 1, True, True, 0, atl3270Tool, ErrMsg) <> S_OK Then
    'Terminate
End If
```

Comment: looks like you are trying to convert vb code to c# in .net 3.5. the issue you have is making your `atDirectoryObject` to work with c#. i suggest you take a look at these topics 1 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a79b4y(v=vs.100).aspx   2 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173184(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Just a quick note, there is NO dynamic typing in C#, or VB. They are both static languages. I will never get why C# decided to confuse a whole bunch of people with their "dynamic" keyword. It should have been "latebound".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late binding is easy to do in vb.net.  So take advantage of .NET's support for writing code in different languages, add a vb.net class library project to wrap the COM component.

The "atl" prefix on the identifier name is curious.  ATL is an acronym for ActiveX Template Library, a C++ library that is very popular to write COM components.  By default it creates servers that support dual binding, both late and early.  For early binding you need a type library, it gets embedded into the executable by a default in an ATL project.  So make sure that you are not wasting an opportunity here to write early bound C# code.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, select the DLL.  If you get no complaints then you're golden, use Object Browser to look at the generated interop library.

Comment: A note -- sometimes, you will not be able to easily construct an instance of the COM object in C# using early binding. You will have to use the [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) class to dynamically create an instance of the object. Use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeName)` if that happens.

Comment: That's called late binding :)

Comment: It's a very limited example of late binding, yeah. But the only purpose of it in this case is because sometimes the constructor for the COM object is hidden from .NET. Unlike in NET 4.0 with its dynamic keyword, he still won't be able to comfortably invoke methods on an object instantiated that way.